# Visual Studio freeze all threads except main and current

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio, is there any easy way to freeze all threads except the main and the current?

Comment: What do you mean "in Visual Studio"? Do you mean in the debugger?

Comment: Yes in the debugger!

Comment: Sure, use the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window.  Freeze and Thaw commands in the context menu.  Works on multiple selected threads.  Poke around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.  It is Visual.

Answer (score 0):

Just moving Hans Passant's answer from his comment to an actual answer:

> Sure, use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window. Freeze and
>   Thaw commands in the context menu. Works on multiple selected threads.

Personally I didn't realize at first that you could multi-select all the threads